# PayPal recurring payment (Subscription button) payment response

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I'm using recurring payment (subscription button) feature in my web application.

I charge 15 USD \ month for a subscription.

This is the HTML form I got from PayPal's generator:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BUTTON_ID">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/IL/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Of course I changed the `BUTTON_ID` field to my real Button ID.

Now, It seems to work fine, but how do I get a notification of a new subscription (not via email) that I can handle by code?

I'm working with ASP.NET 4.0, Javascript & jQuery.

I'd love some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will find the solution: https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Sample code: https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples